# How to test Netbeans 6.7 Plugin?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, plugins, testing

I created a simple netbeans plugin (see [this tutorial](http://silveiraneto.net/2008/02/24/netbeans-your-first-plugin/)) and now i wanna test e.g. the Actionlistener.

But how can this be done ?

to be more specific

- what test frameworks suit netbeans plugin development ?
- how to create a test setup which emulates enough of netbeans e.g. to test the simple actionlistener ?

**Update**

a practical example :

I registered my Action in the Tools Menue, how can i test the "click" on the menue entry ?

Comment: What kind of tests do you want to perform? a general 'does it always work and doesn't crush', or something else?

Comment: at first i need some directions for 'simple' Tests, ill update the description to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into http://jemmy.netbeans.org/ and http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/gui_testing_on_the_netbeans

Or sth. from here
http://www.junit.org/taxonomy/term/6

Answer (score 2):

Jemmy had moved to https://jemmy.dev.java.net/ also it is not depend on NetBeans modules, so can be used for AWT/Swing/SWT/JavaFX testing.

Another library is Window Licker http://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/ from writers of http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/ which now supports Swing/Ajax.